# How does one indirectly initialize a parent contract using a function in the child contract? (EIP-1167)

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, chainlink, proxy-contracts, clone

So I am creating an implementation contract which I intend to clone multiple times. As per the EIP-1167 standard, I cannot use a constructor in the implementation contract and have to use an 'initialize' function instead.

My issue is that my implementation contract inherits the ChainLink VRF Consumer Base contract. In a regular case, I would have indirectly initialized the ChainLink VRF contract using the constructor in my implementation contract, as shown below:

```
constructor(address vrfCoordinatorV2) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        contractOwner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
```

However, since I intend to make clones, I cannot use a constructor in both, the VRF contract as well as my implementation contract. I have replaced the constructor in the VRF contract with an 'initialize' function as well, as recommended by the OpenZeppelin docs [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable).

I am currently trying to initialize the VRF contract as recommended in the OpenZeppelin docs (see below), however Remix is throwing an error saying I need to override the initialize function in the VRF contract.

Implementation Contract:

```
function initialize(
        address _creator
    ) public initializer {
        VRFConsumerBaseV2.initialize(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
```

VRF Contract:

```
abstract contract VRFConsumerBaseV2 is Initializable {
  error OnlyCoordinatorCanFulfill(address have, address want);
  address public vrfCoordinator;

  function initialize(address _vrfCoordinator) public onlyInitializing {
    vrfCoordinator = _vrfCoordinator;
  }
```

My question is how would I initialize the VRF Contract if I choose to override it? Also, is there a 'best practice' to go about this situation?

Thanks in advance!